# Will Omnifaces work along with MyFaces Trinidad?

Tags: html, richfaces, myfaces, omnifaces, trinidad

The framework for our project is `'MyFaces (2.1.*) Trinidad (2.1.*)'`.  Due to few issues and to support HTML 5, we are thinking of migrating the component library from Trinidad to Omnifaces/Richfaces. 
 As a part of migration process, we are thinking of having both the 'Omnifaces and Trinidad' in parallel for some period of time (So that Trinidad will be removed slowly). Will that work or will it cause any serious problems?

If this plan is going to work, are there any tips/tutorial for having both the component libraries in parallel?

Comment: [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/#what-is-omnifaces) is not a component library in frist place.

Comment: OmniFaces will work with anything :D Also RichFaces is now a dead project, so I wouldn't go this way (but it's very similar to Trinidad, so this a plus).